# Update RecyclerView.Adapter after Camera Intent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So currently, I'm capturing an image and updating it in a `RecyclerView` using the Camera Intent:

```
 private void cameraIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "packagename.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens prior to this is it'll trigger the intent from an `setOnItemClickListener interface` I have created within my `RecyclerView.Adapter` which is called in `onCreate` to populate the data from the web-server (or when triggered by `setVisibleUserHint` as they re-enter the fragment again).

//init camera data

```
if (isCamera) {
   cameraArray = object.getJSONArray(PROFILE_DETAILS_CAMERA_ARRAY_KEY);
   sortAdapter(true, object, cameraArray);
} else {
   galleryArray = object.getJSONArray(PROFILE_DETAILS_GALLERY_ARRAY_KEY);
   sortAdapter(false, object, galleryArray);
}
```

//settings adapters

```
cameraAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterGallery(getActivity(), array, true);
cameraAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewAdapterGallery.onItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void setOnItemClickListener(View view, final int position, String image, final boolean isCamera, boolean isLongClick) {
         clickResponse(view, position, image, isCamera, isLongClick, cameraAdapter, array, object);
     }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(cameraAdapter);
cameraAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

What happens post is within the `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            handleBigCameraPhoto(finalPosition);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
...
}

}
```

handleBigCameraPhoto:

```
private void handleBigCameraPhoto(int position) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        saveFile(f, false, position);
}
```

This works perfectly, it saves the file fine to the web-server but I want to update the adapter when that is successful, and of course I'm unable to restore the adapter object using `outState` or `inState` bundle.

```
cameraArray.put(position, parseFile.getUrl());
userObject.put(PROFILE_DETAILS_CAMERA_ARRAY_KEY, cameraArray);
userObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
           @Override
           public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                     if (cameraAdapter != null) {
                         cameraAdapter.updatePosition(cameraArray, position);
                     }
                } else {
                     Log.e(TAG, "failed " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
           }
});
```

By this point I'm not sure why the `cameraAdapter` isn't updating as it's not returning null and is calling updatePosition().

```
public void updatePosition(JSONArray array, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePositionCalled");
        this.imageList = array;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

If anyone can help me solve this mystery, that would be great! Also, if you need any more code or verification at all, let me know.

**Note**: I currently have the `JSONArray` of objects, position in the adapter and web-server object stored in the `saveInstanceState` bundle and is restored correctly (because when I come out of the `ViewPager` fragment and come back in, thus calling `setUserVisibleHint` it restores the adapter from the web-server correctly).

**Update**: I've created a `getImageList()` method inside the adapter and calling that after the supposed 'update', it's updating the list values but not the list?! So i really do think the problem is with `notifyItemChanged(position)`

```
 public JSONArray getImageList() {
        return imageList;
 }
```

// new call

```
if (e == null) {
    cameraAdapter.updatePosition(cameraArray, position);
    Log.e(TAG, cameraAdapter.getImageList().toString());
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "failed " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

It literally prints out the corresponding values in the list, that has been passed to the adapter, but doesn't seem to update the UI.

**Update II**:

I've had two (now deleted) answers advising me to `notifyDataSetChanged()`, Which makes no difference at all and is counter-productive as it'll rebind the whole adapter within the fragment, thus making it slow. I'm already rebinding the dedicated position (supposedly) with `notifyItemChanged()`.

**Note II**: I'm offering a bounty, **not for lazy and unresearched answers** but for a solution with the very least an explanation, I'd like to know why it's going wrong, so I don't run into the same problem again (not a *quick fix*). I'm already well aware of the different functionalities and components of a `RecyclerView`, `RecyclerView.Adapter` and `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, I'm just having trouble in this particular scenario where the `Activity` is returning a result, but not updating the UI as it should.

Comment: If `updatePosition()` is called then `notifyItemChanged()` must be failing. Are you calling it on the UI thread?

Comment: @Cheticamp I am yes, it's apart of a switch statement where I'm doing the exact same thing for the gallery intent (but that doesn't trigger any changes to the activity, which I feel is where my problem lies).

Comment: OK. That construct for `saveInBackground` with a "done" callback just looks like it will be on a non-UI thread.

Comment: @Cheticamp It's apart of the ParseSDK, `findInBackground` is done in the background but done is on the main ui thread, I've just tried `getActivity().runOnUiThread` to confirm your suspicion but it returned a null pointer exception for `getActivity()`, you think that could lie within the problem i.e. may not be constructing the activity fast enough?

Comment: That makes sense. Don't know about `getActivity()` but, based on what you have said, I would focus on the `notifyItemChanged()` call.

Comment: I suggest you to call e.printStackTrace() instead of Log.e(TAG, "failed " + e.getLocalizedMessage());  Probably there you will see some important info on the error you get.

Comment: @LorenzoBarbagli I certainly will when I'm back at my desk. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you try https://android.jlelse.eu/smart-way-to-update-recyclerview-using-diffutil-345941a160e0

Comment: Can you post the code of camera adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey i think the **issue** is with the line  `this.imageList = array` of below method,

```
public void updatePosition(JSONArray array, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePositionCalled");
        this.imageList = array;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

**Reason :**

The `this.imageList = array` line is **creating a new reference**. It is not updating the old reference which was passed in the Recyclerview. Hence, `notifyItemChanged(position);` is refreshing the view but with the old reference of the array which has not been updated.

**Solution:**

You need to update the method as following:

```
public void updatePosition(String url, int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "updatePositionCalled");
        this.imageList.put(position, url);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

And

```
userObject.put(PROFILE_DETAILS_CAMERA_ARRAY_KEY, cameraArray);
userObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
           @Override
           public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                     if (cameraAdapter != null) {
                         cameraAdapter.updatePosition(parseFile.getUrl(), position);
                     }
                } else {
                     Log.e(TAG, "failed " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
           }
});
```

**Update:**

Also, replace `notifyItemChanged(position)` with `notifyItemInserted(position)`as new item is being inserted here in the Array.

Comment: it's still not working. I am now _really perplexed_ as to what is going on. I really thought this would be the solution. I'll try and more devices and get back to you.

Comment: Hey try with `notifyItemInserted(int)` instead of  `notifyItemChanged(position)` since your inserting a new item.